# Paging is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the below script in jQuery pagination:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/paging.js"></script>
```

but the below error appeared:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).paging is not a function
```

I don't know what the problem can be. Although `paging.js` is loaded it seems that the code does not see the file.

Comment: put the $('#elementId').paging call in a $(document).ready { } . If it's not a race condition issue, make sure the plugin is correctly registered.

Comment: how do you know that paging.js is loaded? check client-side, in the browser's development tools. I'd suspect a problem with the ~/ path, or loading order/readiness first, once that is ruled out, add the part of the code where $().paging is called to your post

Comment: I use this script to call the function 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tableData').paging({limit:5});
            });

Comment: you can try, `var jq = $.noConflict();` and use `jq` instead of  `$`

Comment: Maybe you're trying to call the function before it fully loads. try to run it manually after you know the page is fully loaded to check if you still get the same error or maybe try to run it after a few seconds with setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it worked for me.

I think you may not have gotten the jQuery syntax right

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#table-demo').paging({limit:7}); 
    });
</script>
```